# Kodeine blade template extension not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, acl

I have used kodeine for Laravel user roles and permissions. No problem in installation and all the migrations. In documentation of kodeine/laravel-acl there is Blade Template Extension so the code to check users role is :

```
// @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is('admin|moderator'))
// would be
@role('admin|moderator')
    // content allowed for admin's only
@endrole

// @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->can('create.user|edit.user''))
// would be
@permission('create.user|edit.user') 
    // content if user can edit or create users.
@endpermission
```

I used the same code but it doesn't works at all. when i use

```
@role('admin')
    <h1>admin</h1>
@endrole
```

it displays @role('teacher')

**Note:** I'm using laravel 5. I have migrated the database and added data as well. like roles , permissions and all .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use master branch.

```
"kodeine/laravel-acl": "dev-master"
```

Blade template has been added only on master branch, it'll be backported on the week.

[For more information click here](https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/issues/63)